# Ruby on rails : uninitialized constant Zip::File::Create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zip, rubyzip

I'm trying to zip folder with rubyzip gem, I got this error :

> uninitialized constant Zip::File::Create

this the method that create the zip :

```
def self.zip_pdf( report, paths )
    if File.exist?("#{Rails.root}/tmp/pdf/reports/#{report.reference}.zip")
      FileUtils.rm("#{Rails.root}/tmp/pdf/reports/#{report.reference}.zip")
    end

    directory = File.join( File.dirname( paths[0] ) )
    zipfile_name = File.join( File.dirname( paths[0] ) ) + '.zip'

    Zip::ZipFile.open( zipfile_name, Zip::ZipFile::Create ) do |zipfile|
      Dir[ File.join( directory , '*' ) ].each do |file|
        zipfile.add( file.basename( file ), file )
      end
    end

  end
```

I followed the doc but still don't know why it show that error !

Comment: Do you require the gem?  `require 'zip'`

Comment: yes i did @SaraTibbetts

Comment: From the gem documentation I'm seeing `Zip::File.open(zipfile_name, Zip::File::CREATE) do |zipfile|`. Rather than `Zip::ZipFile` have you tried `Zip:File`?

Comment: I did a mistake , it's CREATE instead of Create ;)